SQL Case when statement with hardcoded values
Hi I using the below query to get values FR20 and FR40 when France is selected under my country attribute I am using the below query but not able to get the values.
select case when ${Country} = 'France'
           then (select 'FR20' as ID union select 'FR40' as ID)
       END as ID

Can anyone help me on this if i am using the wrong syntax ?
I tried the above query.

Please tag your RDBMS, see here why that's important: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

I case expression can only return one value, i.e. your UNION can't be used.

No idea what you want to do. Please provide both sample input data and also the expected result as tables in your question. Also read How To Create A Good Example
